# Найти уникальные (ни разу не повторяющееся) числа массива?

Tags: javascript

Массив может быть любой, например такой `[1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,0,1,1,0]`. Т.е. результат должен быть `(2,3)`.
У кого какие идеи будут? 
Помогите, плииз)

А то мой вариант подтягивает и повторяющиеся числа.

```
function unique(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function (item, index) {
        return arr.indexOf(item) === index
    })
}
console.log(unique(array)) // [1, 2, 3, 0]
```

И если будет возможность объяснить новичку детально, то вообще огонь будет! 
Всем заранее спасибо.

Comment: а вы уже что-нибудь пытались сделать?

Comment: исправилась, добавила свой вариант решения.

Comment: Я написал свой вариант, если он вам подходит, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом, либо посмотрите другие ответы

Answer (score 3):

```
const test = [1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,0,1,1,0];


const getUniqElements = (arr) => {
  const occurrences = {};
  // считаем сколько раз каждый элемент встречается в массиве
  arr.forEach(el => {
    if(occurrences[el]) occurrences[el]++;
    else occurrences[el] = 1
  })

  // берем только те элементы, которые попались 1 раз
  return Object.keys(occurrences).filter(key => occurrences[key] === 1)
}

console.log(getUniqElements(test))
```

Сначала считаем вхождение элементов в массив, а потом берем только те, которые появляются один раз

Answer (score 0):

Еще варик

```js
const test = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  fUnic = (arr) => arr.filter((e, i) => arr.indexOf(e, i + 1) == -1 && arr.lastIndexOf(e, i - 1) == -1);
console.log(fUnic(test));
```

Comment: а зачем `indexOf`и `lastIndexOf` одновременно?

Comment: Достаточно посмотреть на вывод консоли после fUnic = (arr) => arr.forEach((e, i)=>console.log(`${i}: ${arr.indexOf(e, i + 1) == -1},${arr.lastIndexOf(e, i - 1) == -1}`));` и станет понятно.

Comment: `"0: false,false"
"1: false,false"
"2: false,false"
"3: false,false"
"4: true,true"
"5: false,false"
"6: true,true"
"7: false,false"
"8: false,false"
"9: false,true"
"10: false,false"
"11: true,false"
"12: true,false"`

Comment: А далее просто булева математика, то есть в результирующий массив войдут только элементы, отвечающие условию `true&&true`

Comment: спасибо, за ваш варик, он мне очень нравится! мне его легче понять.

Comment: Да не за что, но.... у **ThisMan** наоборот более читаемый код. По моему предельно просто написано.

Comment: только у меня возник вопрос. скажите, а почему i + 1 и i - 1 прописываем? почему нельзя ограничится просто i? Простите если это совсем тупой вопрос. Я только учусь

Comment: @KeepsKeeps, не нужно извиняться - вопрос не тупой. Здесь неудобно писать код, и кнопка чата не появилась. Поэтому ответ дал Вам в песонице - https://codepen.io/qwerty_wasd/pen/MBPgOB